# Express Socket.io example server not working

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I'm trying to learn socket.io and their example for Express isnt working. Heres my code:

```
app.js:
var express = require('express')
  , routes = require('./routes')
  , user = require('./routes/user')
  , server = require('http').createServer(app)
  , path = require('path')
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(app);

var app = express();

app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(require('less-middleware')({ src: __dirname + '/public' }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

server.listen(3000);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.jade');
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

and my index.jade file:

```
extends layout

block content
        script(src="/node_modules/socket.io/lib/socket.io.js")
        script(
          var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
          socket.on('news', function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
          });
          )
```

When I go to my localhost the browser just keeps waiting on a response. It eventually times out.

Most of the other questions related to this question had some odd implementation of the example code. I'm literally just trying to implement it as they show.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is you are creating `app` after you are creating `io`. So this line

```
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(app);
```

is effectively the same as

```
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(undefined);
```

remove this line

```
var app = express();
```

And somewhere between the first line and `io = require('socket.io')` add `, app = express()`